# How set initial values for stored property with initializers?

Tags: cocoa, swift2, nsviewcontroller

This code doesn't work.

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: NSTextField!

    var guessScore : Int

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override init(){
        super.init()
        guessScore = 1
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

before calling super.init(), all your properties must be initialized (they have to have some 'default' value), Please read apple docs.

```
override init(){
    guessScore = 1
    super.init()
}
```

Comment: or directly `var guessScore : Int = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code produces:
[image]

So you may want to simply follow the instructions given by Xcode and override the designated initializer:

```
var guessScore: Int

override init?(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    guessScore = 1
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    guessScore = 1
    super.init(coder: coder)
}
```

Or directly without any initializer, provide a default value:

```
var guessScore: Int = 1
```